# Python 3 Pyfirmata timesleep issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, firmata

I have a question regarding the Python3 time `sleep()` function. My set up is consisted of the Arduino UNO running Firmata firmware and a PC/laptop running python code using pyfirmata library.

What I am trying to do is to analog write to a PWM pin from a list of values (100 values in this case). I also want them to output in every 0.001 second or 1 ms. Therefore, technically, 100 values in 0.001s/each would take ~0.1 sec to complete.

Then the problem happened when I used timer to see how long it would take. It only achieved ~0.1 sec total when Google Chrome was opened on certain websites (I know it seems weird, but it's true 100%). Even when I minimized Google Chrome, the total time would slow down to 1.6s consistently until I opened Chrome again.

Then I tried to take off my `time.sleep(0.001)` in my loop then it worked fine regardless the appearance of Chrome or not.

I really want to understand why and a solution for this case. Maybe an alternative of `time.sleep`? Here is my code in python. You can load the firmata sketch from Arduino IDE.

Also note at higher value of `time.sleep()`, everything works fine with or without Chrome opened.

```
import pyfirmata
import time
from timeit import default_timer as timer

board = pyfirmata.Arduino("COM4", baudrate = 115200)
pwmPin = board.get_pin('d:5:p') #digital pin 5 pwm mode

my_points = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100]

def LoadWaveform():
   rate = 1/1000
   #print (my_points)
   while True:
      start = timer()
      for i in range(len(my_points)):
         pwmPin.write(my_points[i]/300)
         #time.sleep(rate)

      end = timer()
      print ("Total time run: ", end - start)
      time.sleep(1)

LoadWaveform()
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Python documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep :

> The suspension time may be longer than requested by an arbitrary amount, because of the scheduling of other activity in the system.

I assume you are running on a Windows machine, but most typical pc operating systems would have the same issue: waiting 1 second is actually equal to waiting 1 second + some small extra unwanted delay because the OS also allows other programs to run.
Those other programs need to sleep() for the OS to be able to get back to your program as well. Or maybe there was a very high priority task that took some extra time away from your python program's thread.

If you want to read more about OSs, threads, multitasking... Then this link and the other chapters before and after this one are a good starting point:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-in-operating-system/